# In perforce how can I undo a resolve -am?

Tags: perforce

P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2013.2/938876 (2014/09/23)

I had some changes in the default changelist that I tried to shelve.  It said I couldn't because I needed to resolve with some other changelist.  It stuck my files in some other changelist.  After looking at the differences, I saw that I wanted to keep all my changes and accept nothing from the other changelist.  Thinking that "-am" meant "accept mine", I ran "p4 resolve -am".  Then there was a "Duuuuhhhhh" momemt when I remembered that "-am" means "auto-merge".

Q: How can I "undo" the automerge that just happened so as to restore what I had ?

Answer (score 2):

If you were able to shelve successfully at some point you can get the pre-resolve files back from the shelf via "p4 unshelve".

As a *general* rule you can't undo the results of a resolve operation to get the "yours" file back, since the workspace file isn't backed up anywhere.

Since this was an automerge, one option would be to try to run the merge in reverse.  You started with A(base)+AB(theirs)+AC(yours), and now you have ABC(merged) -- so you want to set up a merge that'll produce AC.  That'd be AB(base)+A(theirs)+ABC(yours)=AC(merged) -- basically you want to find the "base" and "theirs" from the automerge and reverse them, using the merged result as "yours".  Run "p4 resolved -o" to find the "base" and "theirs" file from the previous merge, then run "p4 print" to get those file contents and use "p4 merge3" to run the 3-way merge algorithm with the three appropriate inputs and the output should be your original file (in theory).

Comment: No, it said the shelve attempt was aborted.  Here's the message...

Shelve aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 shelve -c 964320'.

Comment: "p4 changes -c <clientspec> -s shelved" shows nothing.  "p4 changes -c <clientspec> -s pending" shows the 964320 changelist

Comment: When I do a "p4 resolve -am", and it merges changes, does it change the file in my workarea ?  If not, could I recover using those unchaged files ?

Comment: Yes it does, which is why you can't use that file to recover.  A resolve changes the workspace file ("yours").  One other option is to try to run the merge in reverse (since it was an automerge that might work).  I'll edit my answer in a sec with some hints as to how you might do that.

Comment: Added a somewhat cryptic paragraph on how to do the merge magic.  This happens to be right in my wheelhouse since I wrote `p4 undo` (this is the same basic process, you just have to do it manually in this case), but it's a little difficult to walk someone through remotely.  :P  If you need help I recommend posting on the Perforce forums, I still lurk there and it's easier to do back-and-forth there than on stackoverflow.